# How to add tags to my fragments during initialising them inside a view pager adapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

This is my code; the Addviewer, dataviewer and settingsviewer are my fragment class. I want to give each method a tag during intialising so that I can use them within another fragment or mainactivity.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class viewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    ArrayList<Fragment> arf;

    public viewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        arf = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
        arf.add(new DataViewer());
        arf.add(new AddViewer());
        arf.add(new SettingsViewer());
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return arf.get(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return arf.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: ' I want to give each method a tag during intialising' what do you mean by this?

Comment: During the moment when the fragments are created, in the viewpager constructor ,I wanted to set a tag to each fragment to access them later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [PagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html)'s instantiateItem(...) and destroyItem(...) methods to track your Fragment's creation/destruction.  Or you could always just setArguments(Bundle b) on your Fragment during construction.  Ex.

```
    private SparseArray<Fragment> registeredFragments = new SparseArray<>();

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        Fragment fragment = (Fragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position);  
        //TODO check if it's the type you want, and set the tag
        registeredFragments.put(position, fragment);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
        registeredFragments.remove(position);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks .But i fixed it by using google guidelines for communicating between fragments without the use of tag within the fragments.Anyways i came to know about sparsearray in android.